# Creating Predicate to Test the Number of Relationship

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nspredicate

Say I have a Business object in core data. The Business object may or may not have phones.

I want to create an NSPredicate object where only Businesses with Phones would work.

How would I do so?

```
    NSPredicate * thePredicate5= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"Phones.count > 0"];
```

or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSPredicate * thePredicate5= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NONE Phones == nil"];
```

or

```
NSPredicate * thePredicate5= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY Phones != nil"];
```

I didn't know the answer when I first read your question but it caught my attention. I read the documentation and did some experimenting on one of my projects (iphone app that uses Core Data and sqlite) and the attached code seems to do what you wanted, but I cannot guarantee that it is the correct solution.

Comment: I looked that up. It should be Phones.@count >0 . I mean ANY Phones!=nil would work too. Given that ALL Phones are not !=nil and hence if there is ANY Phones that's not !nil it'll work too. Though technically is not the answer.